# How can display 'o' inside x marker in legend in python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I need to edit the legend by displaying the 'o' inside 'x', which I used to mark parts of curves, but I couldn't solve this since I used a complicated way to highlight High and low parts.

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 15))
ax = fig.add_subplot( 2, 1, 1 )
bx = fig.add_subplot( 2, 1, 2 )

ax.plot( time1List, tempList, marker='x', linestyle='', zorder=100 )
ax.plot( time2List, fit_func( time2List, *sol ), zorder=0 )
ax.set_title('Fitting whole MPs on standrad thermal profile ', fontweight='bold', fontsize=25)
ax.set_xlabel('cycles', fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Thermal regime', fontsize=20)
ax.set_yticks( [-40,-20,0,25,50,75,100,125,150] )
#patch = Patch(facecolor='orange', edgecolor='r', label='Color patch')
#lgd = ax.legend(handles=[time1List, time2List, patch], loc='lower right')
#add_patch(lgd)
#ax.legend(loc='best')

red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='High regime')
blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Low regime')
plt.legend(handles=[red_patch, blue_patch], loc='best', fontsize=20)

bx.plot( time1List, tempList, marker='x', linestyle='' )
bx.plot( time2List, fit_func( time2List, *sol ) )
bx.plot( rampX, rampY, linestyle='', marker='o', markersize=10, fillstyle='none', color='r')
bx.plot( topX, topY, linestyle='', marker='o', markersize=10, fillstyle='none', color='#00FFAA')
bx.plot( botX, botY, linestyle='', marker='o', markersize=10, fillstyle='none', color='#80DD00')
bx.set_title('Fitting part of MPs on standrad thermal profile ', fontweight='bold', fontsize=25)
bx.set_xlabel('cycles', fontsize=20)
bx.set_ylabel('Temperature [℃]', fontsize=20)
bx.set_xlim( [ 0, 800 ] )
plt.show()
```

[image: img]

Any suggestions on how I can fix this issue?

Comment: The code has lots of irrelevant details but I can't find where you are drawing those markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are plotting twice to get that crosshair marker. You won't be able to create a legend with a crosshair with any standard method that way with your approach of creating that marker.

You can use `$\\bigotimes$` to get the marker directly. Then using `legend` will be straightforward. Just define `label` for each object in your plot for it to show in the legend:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

X = np.arange(10)
Y1 = np.arange(10)
Y2 = np.arange(10)/2 + 3

attrs = {'marker': '$\\bigotimes$', 'linestyle': '', 'markersize': 10, 'markeredgewidth': 0.5}
ax.plot(X, Y1, c = 'g', label='Y1', **attrs)
ax.plot(X, Y2, c = 'r', label='Y2', **attrs)
ax.legend()
```

[image]